# Add visual fox pro database as a linked server in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-migration, visual-foxpro

I have a Visual Fox Pro Database (.DCX file with associated .DBF files) that I'm trying to convert to a more useful format, such as Microsoft SQL.

How can I add a Visual Fox Pro database as a linked server, using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?  The VFP database requires no login or password, as far as I can tell.

Thank you.

/edit: I would also be happy if I could figure out a way to access a Visual Fox Pro database through Access 2007 on Windows 7.  I've installed the Visual Fox Pro OLE DB driver, and can pull tables one-at-a-time into excel, but I can't seem to use Access to access OLE DB resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [How to add a Visual FoxPro database to SQL Server as a linked server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199131)

Comment: I'm pretty new to dealing with SQL databases.  I see a script I assume I'm supposed to run from within SQL Management Studio.  How exactly do I do that?

Comment: You want to run the [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) command in SSMS using the parameters shown in the script.